# Java XML Parsing with HTML Entities

Tags: java, xml, dom, unicode

I'm trying to create a Webdav servlet using the Litmus test case.

So I'm trying to parse this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<propertyupdate xmlns='DAV:'>
 <set>
      <prop>
           <high-unicode xmlns='http://example.com/neon/litmus/'>&#65536;
           </high-unicode>
      </prop>
 </set>
</propertyupdate>
```

Using the default document builder I try to get the value inside the `high-unicode` tag:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = req.getReader();
byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(bufferedReader);

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
documentBuilderFactory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
documentBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(false);
documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);

DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
documentBuilder.setEntityResolver(new XMLFilterImpl());

Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
document.setXmlStandalone(true);
document.setStrictErrorChecking(false);

document.normalize();

Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
NodeList childList = rootElement.getChildNodes();

for (int i = 0; i < childList.getLength(); i++) {

    Node currentNode = childList.item(i);
    Node valueNode = currentNode.getFirstChild().getFirstChild();
    String propValue = valueNode.getTextContent();
}
```

I'm expecting the value `propValue` to be:

```
&#65536;
```

but instead it is:

```
Ѐ
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you!